# Use cases and syntax for non-object constructor functions?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

Currently reading js.info and came upon this:

> "Let’s note once again – technically, any function (except arrow functions, as they don’t have this) can be used as a constructor. It can be run with new, and it will execute the algorithm above. The “capital letter first” is a common agreement, to make it clear that a function is to be run with new."

This is the function they included but it doesn't seem to portray what they described. I also couldn't get it to run at all (several errors).

```
// create a function and immediately call it with new
let user = new function() {
  this.name = "John";
  this.isAdmin = false;

  // ...other code for user creation
  // maybe complex logic and statements
  // local variables etc
};
```

**I'm curious what this would look like in practice and what use cases exist for a constructor function that does not return/pertain to an object?**

Comment: "function that does not return/pertain to an object" it is an object https://jsfiddle.net/0x9bLtc7/2/

Comment: "*I also couldn't get it to run at all (several errors).*" but the code is correct. Unless you've removed any of the errors, it does run and it does exactly what it should. "*what use cases exist for a constructor function that does not return/pertain to an object?*" pretty much all constructor functions will not return *explicitly*. So, I'm not sure why the question is here. What use-case would there be for a constructor function if it always needed to return its instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for use cases: constructor functions are de facto object factories. It might be that you want to hide complicated/non-standard construction details from client code while maintaining a familiar construction API using `new`. The ability to return any object you like from a constructor function invoked with `new` enables this.

### More info

Let's rearrange your code to make it a little easier to follow (this is only marginally different in that the constructor function now will have an inferred name `'F'`):

```js
let F = function() {
  this.name = "John";
  this.isAdmin = false;

  // ...other code for user creation
  // maybe complex logic and statements
  // local variables etc
};
let user = new F; // or `new F();` if you prefer, parens are optional
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(user) === F.prototype) // true
```

When `F` is invoked with `new`:

- A new object `o` is immediately created, with its [[Prototype]] set to refer to the `.prototype` property of function `F`.
- The `this` value inside F is set to be `o` for the duration of the invocation of `F` as a constructor function.
- The `.constructor` property of `o` is set to point to `F`
- The return value of `F` is automatically set to be `o` if no value is explicitly returned.

Most constructor functions do not *explicitly* return an object. This is because invocation with `new` *implicitly* creates a new object, `o`, configured according to the rules of prototypical inheritance; `o` is set to be the `this` value used for the duration of the execution of the constructor function, and `o` is automatically and implicitly returned if no value is explicitly returned.

That said, programmers can instead *explicitly* return any object they like from a constructor function, and this overrides and prevents the implicit return.

Any function that implements the [`[[Construct]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#constructor) internal method can be used as a constructor function with `new` (and `super`).

Ordinary function declarations (`function foo() { ... }`) and class constructors (`class foo { constructor() {} }`) can be used as constructor functions. Fat arrow functions, object literal methods, async functions and class methods cannot be used as constructor functions because they don't have the `[[Construct]]` internal method.